# How to correctly read information from OBJ file and use it to render a model with DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx, .obj

I'm trying to render a model in OBJ file format with DirectX. I'm using simple cube model, but I get some really strange results(picture below)

I've tried to render a cube by filling vertecies array manually and it worked pretty good. After studing OBJ file format I've thougth that I should do the similar thing, but I don't understand why this is not working.

---

Sending two functions and structs descriptions:

1. initGeometry
      
   In this function I set up my geometry, shaders and read information from file. I think that I do something wrong at the end of this function, because I didn't change shaders part and initializations part, only added new way to fill up a vertex array
2. render
   This function didn't changed at all from my first version, where I filled up a vertecies array mannualy.
3. Structs
   Just some structs descriptions.

```cpp
HRESULT RenderDevice::initGeometry() {

    ///////READING INFO FROM FILE//////////
    ifstream *inp = new ifstream("test.obj");
    ofstream *out = new ofstream("result.txt");
    char str[256];
    while (!inp->eof()) {
        inp->getline(str, 256);
        meshInfo.coord.push_back(new std::string(str));
    }

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    ID3DBlob *pVSBlob = NULL;
    hr = compileShaderFromFile(L"texture.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0", &pVSBlob);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Can't compile Vertex Shader", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateVertexShader(pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &g_pVertexShader);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        pVSBlob->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] = {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"NORMAL", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };
    UINT numElemenets = ARRAYSIZE(layout);

    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElemenets, pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), &g_pVertexLayout);
    pVSBlob->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(g_pVertexLayout);
    ID3DBlob *pPSBlob = NULL;
    hr = compileShaderFromFile(L"texture.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0", &pPSBlob);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Can't compile Pixel Shader", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }

    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreatePixelShader(pPSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pPSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &g_pPixelShader);
    pPSBlob->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }
    pPSBlob = NULL;
    hr = compileShaderFromFile(L"texture.fx", "PSSolid", "ps_4_0", &pPSBlob);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Can't compile Solid Pixel Shader", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreatePixelShader(pPSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pPSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &g_pPixelShaderSolid);
    pPSBlob->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    /////////SPLITING INFO INTO DIFFERENT VECTORS/////////////////
    for (int i = 0; i < meshInfo.coord.size(); i++) {
        if (meshInfo.coord[i]->c_str()[0] == 'v' && meshInfo.coord[i]->c_str()[1] != 'n') {
            float tmpx, tmpy, tmpz;
            sscanf_s(meshInfo.coord[i]->c_str(), "v %f %f %f", &tmpx, &tmpy, &tmpz);
            meshInfo.positions.push_back(XMFLOAT3(tmpx, tmpy, tmpz));
        } else if (meshInfo.coord[i]->c_str()[0] == 'v' && meshInfo.coord[i]->c_str()[1] == 'n') {
            float tmpx, tmpy, tmpz;
            sscanf_s(meshInfo.coord[i]->c_str(), "vn %f %f %f", &tmpx, &tmpy, &tmpz);
            meshInfo.normals.push_back(XMFLOAT3(tmpx, tmpy, tmpz));
        } else if (meshInfo.coord[i]->c_str()[0] == 'f') {
            int iX, iY, iZ, nX, nY, nZ;
            sscanf_s(meshInfo.coord[i]->c_str(), "f %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d", &iX, &nX, &iY, &nY, &iZ, &nZ);
            meshInfo.indexiesPoints.push_back(iX);
            meshInfo.indexiesPoints.push_back(iY);
            meshInfo.indexiesPoints.push_back(iZ);

            meshInfo.indexiesNormals.push_back(nX);
            meshInfo.indexiesNormals.push_back(nY);
            meshInfo.indexiesNormals.push_back(nZ);
        }
    }

    meshInfo.indexiesAmount = meshInfo.indexiesPoints.size();

    meshInfo.vertexAmount = meshInfo.positions.size();
    meshInfo.normalsAmount = meshInfo.normals.size();
    Vertex *vertices = new Vertex[meshInfo.indexiesAmount];

    //////////////FILLING VERTECIES ARRAY///////////////
    for (int i = 0; i < meshInfo.indexiesAmount; i++) {
        vertices[i].normal.x = meshInfo.normals[meshInfo.indexiesNormals[i] - 1].x;
        vertices[i].normal.y = meshInfo.normals[meshInfo.indexiesNormals[i] - 1].y;
        vertices[i].normal.z = meshInfo.normals[meshInfo.indexiesNormals[i] - 1].z;

        vertices[i].pos.x = meshInfo.positions[meshInfo.indexiesPoints[i] - 1].x;
        vertices[i].pos.y = meshInfo.positions[meshInfo.indexiesPoints[i] - 1].y;
        vertices[i].pos.z = meshInfo.positions[meshInfo.indexiesPoints[i] - 1].z;
    } 

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * meshInfo.indexiesAmount;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
    ZeroMemory(&initData, sizeof(initData));
    initData.pSysMem = vertices;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &initData, &g_pVertexBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }


    ///////////////////FILLING INIXIES ARRAY///////////////////
    WORD *indixies = new WORD[meshInfo.indexiesAmount];
    for (int i = 0; i < meshInfo.indexiesAmount; i++) {
        indixies[i] = meshInfo.indexiesPoints[i];
    }

    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(int) * meshInfo.indexiesAmount;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    initData.pSysMem = indixies;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, &initData, &g_pIndexBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    g_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(g_pIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);

    g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(ConstantBuffer);
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &g_pCBMatrixes);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

```cpp
void RenderDevice::render() {
    float clearColor[4] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
    g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(g_pRenderTargetView, clearColor);

    g_pImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(g_pDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);
    updateLigth();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        updateMatrix(MX_SETWORLD, i * (XM_PI * 2) / 6);
        g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(g_pVertexShader, NULL, 0);
        g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &g_pCBMatrixes);
        g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(1, 1, &g_pCBLigth);
        g_pImmediateContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &g_pCBMatrixes);
        g_pImmediateContext->PSSetConstantBuffers(1, 1, &g_pCBLigth);
        g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(g_pPixelShader, NULL, 0);
        g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(meshInfo.indexiesAmount, 0, 0);
    }


    g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(g_pPixelShaderSolid, NULL, 0);
    for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
        updateMatrix(m, 0);
        g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(meshInfo.indexiesAmount, 0, 0);
    }

    g_pSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

```cpp
typedef struct Vertex {
    XMFLOAT3 pos;
    XMFLOAT3 normal;
}Vertex;

typedef struct MeshInfo {
    int vertexAmount;
    int normalsAmount;
    vector<XMFLOAT3> positions;
    vector<XMFLOAT3> normals;
    vector<string*> coord;
    vector<int> indexiesPoints;
    vector<int> indexiesNormals;
    int indexiesAmount;
}MeshInfo;


typedef struct ConstantBuffer {
    XMMATRIX mWorld;
    XMMATRIX mView;
    XMMATRIX mProjection;
    XMFLOAT4 vLigthDir[2];
    XMFLOAT4 vLigthColor[2];
    XMFLOAT4 vOutputColor;
}ConstantBuffer;
```

I expect to see 6 cubes in my program's window, 
[but I get this thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2yKw.png)

Comment: You might want to look at [this header](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMesh/blob/master/Utilities/WaveFrontReader.h) as well as [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found a solution to my problem. The main problem was to make a correct order for vertecies to draw. But in .OBJ files only **UNIQUE** vertices, normals and texture coordinates are written. Also they are separated from each other (for example it can be 8 **UNIQUE** vertex coordinates and 6 **UNIQUE** normals coordinates). The main thing is happening in part, where are faces are described. Each face is pointing to a specific index of position, normal and texture coordinate, meaning that we can use same normals, positions and texture coordinates different times(I know it's obviously). And I realised that in my realisation I don't need indexies array at all, because Vertecies array, that I've filled up was already a model! And I ended up using method *Draw* instead of *DrawIndexed* in *ID3D11DeviceContext*. [image: This is the result that I get with more complex shapes like Susanna from blender]

Answer (score 0):

OBJ file format stores indices using one-based numbering (first vertex index is 1) [Wavefron Obg file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). DirectX uses zero-based numbering (first vertex index is 0, same as C, C++).

So you should convert indices values to use them. You can do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < meshInfo.indexiesAmount; i++) {
    indixies[i] = meshInfo.indexiesPoints[i] - 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't realise it from the start. Still get messed up result, but it's looking a little bit better. 
I feel that there is a problem in normals and points array.